# ios load images from web server and show on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

For the iPhone 5.0 (ARC) I am getting lot of image(image url's) and text data from server in a json form. My requirement is to load the first five images from the server and when the user scrolls down the next five images load and so on. I need to show it in a UITableViewCell. By doing this I can reduce the network calls and make the application faster on the device.

Currently, I am using a background thread to load images, but they continuously load in the background. I don't want to do it like this.

Comment: I don't see a single question mark in this post.  Is there a question?

Comment: Nope ... there is demand for sample code .....!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly encourage you to use the [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) framework (that is really great and complete for all network-related tasks).

It comes with a category on `UIImageView` that allows you to set the `UIImageView`'s `image` directly from an `NSURL`, managing everything for you in the background, like downloading the image or fetching it from its cache, cancelling the request if you change the `URL` later to avoid useless requests, etc.

Then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can simply write this kind of code:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:yourURL];
```

And you're done. It will work even when the recycling mechanism of the `UITableView` is in action when you scroll, which would be quite a pain to manage using other methods.

Comment: You imported and integrated the `AFNetworking` framework in your project/workspace and imported the right header, of course, before using the line, right? _Just saying "doesn't seem to be working" is not very verbose if you want some help by the way, we can't guess what error message you have ;)_

Comment: LOL! Of course I did everything ;) Problem is the url I specified doesn’t have an extension like JPG or PNG.. I tried specifying some other, and it works just fine.. But i don’t see a big change in loading the images.. Anyways it is just fine for now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It's a really neat library to download images asynchronously and also caches them.